# How can I create a REST endpoint in a Nexus2 (2.13.0-01) plugin via siesta?

Tags: java, jax-rs, nexus

I tried to create a REST endpoint for a plugin for Nexus2 with the following class:

```
@Path(NexusPlugin.URI)
@Named
@Singleton
public class NexusPlugin extends ComponentSupport implements Resource {

  public static final String URI ="/nexusplugin";

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public Response get(){
        return Response.ok("Config Updated").build();
    }
}
```

In my understanding, implementing the Resource interface should be enough and Nexus/siesta should instantiate that class and create the Resource. I do not use any web.xml and I currently do not instantiate that class by myself.

The code is based on the code of the Nexus2 [logging plugin](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/nexus-2.x/plugins/basic/nexus-logging-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/logging/rest/LogResource.java) which also offers a REST endpoint, I might have missed something there.

Siesta returns always something like this as an error:

```
{
"id": "ae015d47-5968-4cb6-88c3-d5615c677c0c",
"message": "No resource available at 'nexusplugin'"
}
```

The Nexus2 log shows the following error:

```
 admin org.sonatype.sisu.siesta.server.internal.SiestaServlet - Processing: GET /nexus/service/siesta/nexusplugin (http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/siesta/nexusplugin)
 2018-01-30 08:40:47,816+0100 DEBUG [esh-1-thread-5] admin org.sonatype.nexus.feeds.record.NexusAuthenticationEventInspector - Successfully authenticated user [admin] from IP address 127.0.0.1
 2018-01-30 08:40:47,816+0100 DEBUG [qtp491414393-52] admin org.sonatype.sisu.siesta.server.internal.mappers.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - (ID e92c848c-d603-4541-bb0c-ddd60fddb5e4) Mapping exception: com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/siesta/nexusplugin
 2018-01-30 08:40:47,820+0100 WARN  [qtp491414393-52] admin org.sonatype.sisu.siesta.server.internal.mappers.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - (ID e92c848c-d603-4541-bb0c-ddd60fddb5e4) Response: [404] ErrorXO{id='e92c848c-d603-4541-bb0c-ddd60fddb5e4', message='No resource available at 'nexusplugin''} mapped from com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException/null for uri: http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/siesta/nexusplugin
 com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/siesta/nexusplugin
```

This is not very helpful though because the error is raised on any arbitrary url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue if finally solved. The dependency of the siesta plugin in the pom.xml needs the following additional line:

```
<type>${nexus-plugin.type}</type>
```

so that it looks like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-siesta-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0-01</version>
        <type>${nexus-plugin.type}</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```